# Lua сгенерировать таблицу два столбца с неповторяющимися строками

Tags: случайные-числа, lua

Необходимо сгенерировать таблицу Lua c двумя значениями, которые не повторяются.
Причем в таблице не должно быть строк типа (a,b) и (b,a).
Такие строки будут считаться одинаковыми (a,b) = (b,a).

Есть пример (вроде пример Mike V.), который генерирует таблицу с одним столбцом неповторяющихся значений:

```
math.randomseed(os.time()) -- first, sets a seed for the pseudo-random generator
math.random(); math.random(); math.random();

local  function my_random(t, from, to)  -- second, exclude duplicates
   local num = math.random (from, to)
   if t[num] then num = my_random(t, from, to) end
   t[num] = num
   return num
end

local t = {}    -- initialize  table with not duplicate values
for i =1, 30 do
  X = my_random (t, 1, 50)
  print (i, "=" ,X)
 end
```

Мне нужно аналогично, но два столбца (Лучше сразу в таблицу Lua загнать):

```
1 -  1,3
2 -  2,4
3 -  4,3
4 -  ...
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробую и тут помочь, только вы не написали какие еще ограничения есть.
Может нужны все возможные комбинации? Тогда нужно вычислить это количество по какой-то формуле и подставить вместо `limit` тут `for i =1, limit do`.

```
math.randomseed(os.time()) 
math.random(); 

local function random2(from, to)
  return  math.random (from, to), math.random (from, to) 
end

local  function my_random(t, from, to)  -- second, exclude duplicates
   local a,b = random2 (from, to)
   if t[a..'_'..b] or t[b..'_'..a] then a,b = my_random(t, from, to) end
   t[a..'_'..b] = {a,b}
   return a,b
end

local limit = 10
local t = {}   
for i =1, limit do
  x,y = my_random (t, 1, limit)
  print (i, "=" ,x,y)
 end
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike V.

Comment: Хорошая стековая переполнялка!  И как отличить `12..3` от `1..23` ?

Comment: @ESkri в небольших размерах таблиц вполне нормально. а насчет последнего - правильное замечание, поправил ответ!

Comment: можно рекурсию заменить на цикл while и не тратить стек вообще

Comment: @ESkri набросайте для интереса

Comment: `repeat a,b = random2 (from, to) until not (t[a..'_'..b] or t[b..'_'..a])`

Comment: @Mike V. Вы правильно написали. Я забыл описать ограничения! Нужно, чтобы a<>b. Это я сделал: ```if t[a..'_'..b] or t[b..'_'..a] or a == b then``` Мне нужно получать все возможные комбинации. Например: если варианты для a b - "1,2,3,4", то получаем "6" комбинаций: ```limit = 6 и x,y = my_random (t, 1, 4)```. Как получить все комбинации не указывая ```limit```?

Comment: Можно так. Первую цифру двузначного числа с заданными условиями можно выбрать 4 способами;
после того как первая цифра определена, вторую можно выбрать уже только тремя
способами, т.к. цифра не может совпасть с той которая на первой позиции.
Итого вариантов 4х3/2=6. Делим на 2 так как "1,2" = "2,1" и т.д.

Comment: я бы не мудрил в таком случае: простым перебором заполнил таблицу всевозможных пар, а уж потом  сделал перемешивание для этой таблицы по моему методу или по предложенному  ESkri